# Polymer CLI install hangs at gecko driver

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to install `polymer-cli` but it hangs here:

```
node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wct-local
> node scripts/postinstall.js

----------
selenium-standalone installation starting
----------

---
selenium install:
from: https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
to: /Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/2.53.1-server.jar
---
chrome install:
from: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_mac64.zip
to: /Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.23-x64-chromedriver
---
firefox install:
from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.10.0/geckodriver-v0.10.0-macos.tar.gz
to: /Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.10.0-x64-geckodriver
```

How can I resolve this? I've already tried using different Node versions, v4 and v6 via NVM. Tried installing an older version 0.14 vs 0.16. Both seem to have the same issue. Tried downloading the geckodriver (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.10.0/geckodriver-v0.10.0-macos.tar.gz), without issues on Chrome. Whats wrong?

Comment: Is that with --verbose? It might be hanging right after the firefox install. Also, I am using jdk8 here with a old version of selenium to achieve success.

Comment: I have the same problem on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: I've the same problem on OSX
It hangs at 
`firefox install:
from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-macos.tar.gz
to: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/wct-local/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.11.1-x64-geckodriver`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my mac. Finally this worked for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me. Still hangs.

Comment: My OS is MacOS latest version and the command line shows what is displayed above, in the question: downloading gecko...

Comment: sudo on npm can lead to a lot of problems - see https://medium.com/@kileras/tldr-please-never-ever-ever-do-sudo-npm-install-its-a-security-risk-and-you-dont-need-to-do-it-525a6b9f067e